# Ensuring two string are not equal and ignoring case

Tags: java

I'm trying to two strings, to ensure that they are different.
How should i go about writing the syntax?

I getting this error consistently
error:  expected
            while(input.!equalsIgnoreCase("W"))

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in):

while((hX != eX && hY != eY) || mX != hX && mY != hY)
        {
            System.out.println("Move WASD: ");
            String input = scn.nextLine();

             while(!(input.equalsIgnoreCase("W")) && input.!equalsIgnoreCase("A") && input.!equalsIgnoreCase("S") && input.!equalsIgnoreCase("D"))
            {
                //Do something
            }
```

Comment: How you are able to compile this code ?

Comment: You can not write `input.!equalsIgnoreCase("D")` , please see explanation in below answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while(input.!equalsIgnoreCase("W"))` should be

```
while(!(input.equalsIgnoreCase("W")))
```

If you are not handling null for input then there can be chance of [**NullPointerException**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) so I woul do `while(!("W".equalsIgnoreCase(input)))`

As per the updated code,the solution is

```
while(!(input.equalsIgnoreCase("W")) && !(input.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) && !(input.equalsIgnoreCase("S")) && !input.equalsIgnoreCase("D")))
            {
                //Do something
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
while(!(input.equalsIgnoreCase("W")))
                {
                    //Do something
                }
```